# android need to compare current and previous event.values of the onSensorChanged method

Tags: java, android

I need to send post request with change in sensor value . It is sending too many requests as the method is called with every change in timestamp(nanosecond). I need to send a request only in change of sensor value. 
I want to compare current event.value with previous event.value

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    TextView metrics,post;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private float timestamp;
    RequestQueue queue;
    //private Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        metrics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metrics);
        post = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        //sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    protected void onStop()
    {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1)
    {
        //Do nothing.
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
        {
            return;
        }

        metrics.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[0]) +"\n"+
                "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[1]) +"\n"+
                "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[2]));

        if ( event.values[0] != || event.values[1] != || event.values[2] != ) {

            RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).
                    getRequestQueue();

            String url ="http://10.46.2.179:8080/?X=" + event.values[0] + "&&Y=" + event.values[1] + "&&Z=" + event.values[2];

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //post.setText(response);
                    //Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //post.setText(error.toString());
                    //Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            });

            MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your `onSensorChanged`

```
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
  @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // only allow one update every 100ms.

            //  if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 150) {


                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                z = 0;
                x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                y = sensorEvent.values[1];
                z = sensorEvent.values[2];

                float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    last_z = z;
                }
            }
```

`last_x` , `last_y` ,`last_z` will have your previous values. Hope this helps

Comment: how do i inititalize these values lastx, lasty, lastz?

Comment: what is the lastUpdate variable for?

Comment: Not able to send request. Didn't understand logic. what values are going into x,y,x and lastx,lasty,lastz

Comment: in xyz the current values are stored where as in last_ variables the previous values of sensor are stored

Comment: When you get values in x y z , do your work send request and on the end store those values in last_ variables next time your x y z will have new values and last_ variables will have previous values

Comment: I think its not storing previous event values, thats why no request is going

Comment: How are you using values?

Comment: I need both previous and current values in same line. I need to send request only when there is a change in previous and current values

Comment: this should be working as i have used this logic in my work.

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thanks

Comment: @RohitPothuraju IF my asnwer helped you dont forget to accept it and rate up so that it may help others in future

Comment: I did but I have lesser than 15 reputations so it will not show publicly

Comment: @RohitPothuraju its okay, its just for other people's so that they can find their right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Sensor Batching](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/batching), more and more smartphones are supporting it. Basically the events are stored in a queue in hardware and periodically are sent to your application all at once. There, you can compare all the results in a single call.

The only line in your code you have to change is:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

adding a fourth parameter you define:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, max_report_latency_ns);
```

Where this max_report_value is:

> When max_report_latency_ns>0, sensor events do not need to be reported as soon as they are detected. They can be temporarily stored in the hardware FIFO and reported in batches, as long as no event is delayed by more than max_report_latency_ns nanoseconds. That is, all events since the previous batch are recorded and returned at once. This reduces the amount of interrupts sent to the SoC and allows the SoC to switch to a lower power mode (idle) while the sensor is capturing and batching data.

Comment: Also, I need to get gyroscope metrics that I can't see at the moment with Nexus 6 emulator in Android studio. Im getting Sensor returned null error. I am taking Magentic Field values at the moment. How do I see Gyroscope values